# как поставить пробелы в String?

Tags: flutter, dart

например, есть `String money = 10000;`, я бы хотел добавить маску к этой строке и вывести его как: 10 000, если 1000 то 1 000, если 100000 то 100 000, если 1000000 то 1 000 000 и тд. пробовал библиотеку `money_formatter` но там запятые вставляются а мне нужны пробелы

Comment: *пробовал библиотеку money_formatter но там запятые вставляются а мне нужны пробелы* Ну, во-первых, можно тупо заменить запятые на пробелы - уж какой-нить replace()-то найдётся. А, во-вторых, разделитель тысяч - параметр настраиваемый (правда, библиотека может не управляться и тупо брать системный, а его менять ради одного приложения некрасиво - но это надо читать маны на библиотеку).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С использованием [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Rz6QPt/1):

```
void main() {
  String s = "1000000";
  s = s.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r"(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))"), (match) => "${match.group(0)} ");
  print(s); // "1 000 000"
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, самое то!